# Gitlab - repository or object not found git lfs error

Tags: git, gitlab, git-lfs

When I am trying to pull new comment from gitlab server using github desktop always there is an error:

```
error downloading object: MyFolder/ImageContainer/ui/cat1.png
batch response: Repository or object not found: https://myplatform.com/443/dima/localo.git/objects/batch
```

I checked my repo link several times, it is: `http://myplatform.com/dima/localo.git`. How to solve it?

I cloned the repo newly to another folder, it works fine but the old one still has the problem.